# MySQL script with procedure (error 1064)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

> mysql> source queries.txt
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
> to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r_id
> INT)
> BEGIN
> SELECT temp.id,SUM(temp.hours*(e.salary/140)) AS cost
> FROM em' at line 1

So i am getting the above error when I compile the following script..
**queries.txt**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pro1(ΙΝ r_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT temp.id,SUM(temp.hours*(e.salary/140)) AS cost 
    FROM employee e INNER JOIN (SELECT r.id,w.hours, w.afm FROM repair r INNER JOIN works w ON r.id=w.id WHERE r.id=r_id) AS temp 
    ON e.afm=temp.afm GROUP BY temp.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The code between begin and end is running just fine if I replace r_id with any int, as shown below:
[image]
As you can see the only difference is at the WHERE statement, where I have placed 20013 instead
of the procedure's parameter r_id. The rest is just a copy paste. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this query directly on your database engine?
May be you have already created this procedure, so that still exists.

Comment: @usermesam0023 i ran the command: "show procedure status" in my database and it returned an empty set... But since its giving me the error it couldn't have saved the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code was right all along.. It's just that the "IN" (in the arguments was was written in greek letters).. So now it is fixed! Thanks everyone for your time, and upvoted for giving it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway try this:

```
   DELIMITER $$
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pro1;

    CREATE PROCEDURE pro1(ΙΝ r_id INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT temp.id, SUM(temp.hours*(e.salary/140)) AS cost 
        FROM employee e
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT r.id, w.hours, w.afm
             FROM repair r
             INNER JOIN
              works w
             ON r.id = w.id WHERE r.id = r_id) AS temp 
        ON e.afm = temp.afm GROUP BY temp.id;

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Run this query in your DB query engine and make sure that there is no trouble with the code. And then use external files to store it.

Comment: Still the same, although it's quite interesting that the error stopped at "SUM(temp.hour*(e.salary/140)) AS", instead of "FROM em" as it did earlier.. I don't know whether this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a very minute one. I actually don't see any issue with your procedure body except the below. Change your end delimiter statement

from

```
END$$
```

to

```
END $$
```

Comment: nah.. doesn't make any difference.. I'm starting to think whether it has something to do with my setup of mysql or something.. However I never had any issue before.